# How can I find the rank for each user?

Tags: matlab, pattern-matching, image-recognition, biometrics

I am having trouble understanding on how can I sort the users according to their rank. I'm using the Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) for developing iris recognition system and I've got the output of the Softmax classifier from the left and right iris.
What I'm going to do is using one of the ranking fusion methods (e.g. the highest rank method, the Borda count method, and the logistic regression method) to fuse the output of both the left and right iris. I completely understand each method how does it work, but I faced problem on how can I find the initial rank for each user. In other words, How can I find the rank for each user before I fed them to any one of the ranking methods?.
Please, any explanation and idea on this will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case you don't have a global rank of the user,
just the ranking of users for each of the examples.
You may treat the answer from your classifier as a ranking method, if it returns a vector of likelihoods of a given iris belonging to each of the users.
Then you may rank the users for the left and right iris separately and fuse the rankings.

Comment: Dear Michal
Thank you for your response,
In fact, the output of my classifier is a matrix of size 224x2240, where 224 is the number of the classes and 2240 is the number of the examples (10 images for each person). Each column represents a vector of probability for each example, where the maximum value represent the best. Do you mean I can rank the users using this matrix?. If, Yes, I'll face another problem which is how can I rank two or more users have the same  probability value?

Comment: You can rank the 224 users for each of the 2240 examples by ranking each of the 2240 rows of the matrix separately. Depending on your task you can then fuse all the rankings for a given user (from 10 available examples). And yes, you will still need to have some breaking ties policy (possibly a random one).

Comment: what do you mean by random one?

Comment: If after fusing there are some ties between users you may just arrange those users in a random way (if you have no more information at your disposal to decide on the final ranking and you don't accept ties that is an acceptable way to deal with the problem).

Comment: Dear Michal, thank you for your help.